# pyodbc with Azure SQL Server, String or binaray data would be truncated. (8152)

Tags: python, azure, pyodbc

I am very much aware of what this issue normally signifies and typical troubleshooting steps. Before you immediately link me to another solution please read the following details:

- My database column I am inserting into is sized `varchar(max)` as it
  often takes multi-sentence strings for this data.
- The string that I am trying to insert at the moment is:

> Chance of light snow today, mostly cloudy.

- Python confirms the length of this string as 42 characters via the `len()` function. (I also added a `strip()` statement to remove new line and leading/trailing spaces
- I have verified that I have the correct order for the values on the INSERT statement in this section of my code so that this value is actually going into the column that I think it is.
- The data is scraped from the web as text using beautiful soup and the `get_text()` method for the css tag.
- When running `SELECT len(<column name>)` against my database, I have inserted over 1000 other values in the current table in this column that are way larger. The largest is 2926 characters. Here's that string for comparison:

> Tips Up March 22, 2019 at 5:00 a.m. Good morning everyone, Steve here with Patrol. Winds last night were out of the Southwest 10-15mph. A slight inversion set up just after close and brought valley clouds to about 6,000ft. Temperatures through the evening reflected that with our coldest temps recorded at Base. Overnight lows however still hovered just above freezing.
>   Today will be a transition day for us here at Crystal as a low pressure system bringing light moisture to the area begins to move inland off the coast. This morning should start off Mostly sunny with a chance for some valley clouds. As we push closer to the afternoon you should expect increasing clouds and a slight chance of showers to develop. Temperatures will be slightly cooler then yesterday and winds will remain moderate out of the Southwest 15-30mph. An overall cooling trend through the weekend will create challenging conditions off piste as our wet spring snow will take longer and longer to thaw out. Stay safe, have fun and I hope to see you out there!
>   Right Angle Sports is currently having a progressive sale- which means 30-50% off retail and East Peak Demo Center gear.
>   Spring Promotions: As the weather heats up, so are the deals!  Emergency Services members including Police, Firefighters and EMT’s receive 50% off walk-up ticket rates now until March 24th. Simply present your ID/Credentials at the ticket window. We’re also taking care of College Students and Teachers this Spring Break with 50% off walk-up ticket rates from March 22nd-31st. Learn More
>   Spring Events: The 2* Freeride World Qualifier will be taking place today on Northway Peak, then on Saturday the 4* Freeride World Qualifier be going down on Silver King!  Come watch as these rippers go big in hopes of landing a spot on the podium!  As always the Mountain Music Series will taking place Saturday from 2-5 p.m. on the Sundeck!  The biggest party of the year is going down March 30th, get your tickets now for the 18th Annual Dirt Bag Ball. The Sturtevant’s Spring Fling will also be taking place next Saturday where you can demo next years gear, followed by Skimo on Sunday the 31st! The fun continues with the Mike Brooks Brewfest on April 6th along with the Red Bull Homerun.  The Last Ditch Effort is back and will be happening April 6th.  To finish up the season, the Elysian Bikini Downhill will be taking place April 20th followed by the Sierra Nevada Spring Splash on April 21st.  We also have some fun Easter activities planned for closing day including Easter Brunch at the Summit House so make your reservations now.  April 21st will be the final day of the 2018-2019 ski and snowboard season so we hope you can join us a few more times before we switch gears to summer.
>   Guest Satisfaction: Please take a few minutes to complete our Guest Survey and let us know how we’re doing. Your feedback is very important to us and we greatly appreciate your time.

I'm looking for ideas on where to start trying to figure out how such a short string is throwing this error in a column that should have FAR more storage space both theoretically and empyrically with other data I've inserted. I thought maybe I was running out of total storage space but the azure portal shows I am utilizing 1% of my available storage.

Comment: You might want to post an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues) that includes a [mcve] and an ODBC trace log.

Comment: Hi Gord, I appreciate the response I just wanted to post in this thread and update in case anyone else comes across this post with the same issue. I have been totally unable to indentify what specifically is the cause for my server to throw this issue however I have managed to get the INSERT statement to finish by using SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF and SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON (before and after the actual query). I did this as a troubleshooting step to see if I could do a before + after comparison to see HOW the string was being truncated once it's inserted into the db and I see no issues with the data.

Comment: For anyone that is thinking to disable ANSI_WARNINGS in order to resolve this issue please be aware that this may cause unexpected data issues. For me, this is simply a pet project in my own home server for fun so this duct-tape solution isn't identifying the root cause of the error but works fine for my non-business test environment.